# Is there such a thing as ant castings?

Tags: soil-amendment, worms, ants

I was reading that ants will kill worms off, so this got me wondering is there such a thing as ant castings since I've found that a type of stinging ants love to move into wood chip piles.

Comment: “Ant castings” as in excrement? What would that be good for and how is that gardening-related?

Comment: Yeah, but the worms can fight back. There is a nematode worm that gets itself eaten by an ant, and then turns the ant into a "zombie" which just climbs up a blade of grass, hangs on, and stays there while the worm eats it starting from the inside and working out. Something else eats the dead ant plus worm - rinse and repeat. Nature isn't all nice and cuddly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, they excrete like all animals, and yes this would contain nutrients. You are unlikely to see that though as they are quite fastidious creatures and like to do their own composting.

You may sometimes see granular material that they have deposited around the entrances to their nest, but this is just material that they have excavated.

In an open compost heap or in the soil things tend to keep themselves in check, so I wouldn't worry too much.